# Jquery flot graph not plotting

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I have the following JS data:

```
var store = [];
store.push([new Date('2012-01-01'), 2]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-02'), 3]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-03'), 4]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-04'), 6]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-05'), 3]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-06'), 4]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-07'), 2]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-08'), 1]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-09'), 4]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-10'), 2]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-11'), 3]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-12'), 6]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-13'), 2]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-14'), 5]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-15'), 4]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-16'), 2]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-17'), 6]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-18'), 6]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-19'), 1]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-20'), 1]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-21'), 1]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-22'), 8]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-23'), 8]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-24'), 13]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-25'), 5]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-26'), 5]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-27'), 1]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-28'), 1]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-29'), 2]);
store.push([new Date('2012-01-30'), 6]);
```

Flot code:

```
$.plot($('.chart'), store);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="chart"></div>
```

My Axis on both the x and y is only showing from -1 to 1.. I can't see the graph plotting at all. Where am i going wrong?

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<html>
<head>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var store = [];
            store.push([new Date(2012, 1, 1)).getTime(), 2]);
            .
            .
            .
            store.push([(new Date(2012, 1, 30)).getTime(), 6]);

            $.plot($('.chart'), store, {
                grid: {hoverable: true},
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",
                    timeformat: "%d.%m.%y",
                        minTickSize: [1,"day"],
                    min: (new Date(2012, 1, 1)).getTime(),
                    max: (new Date(2012, 1, 30)).getTime()
                },
                yaxis: {
                    mode: "number",
                    tickSize: 1
                },
                series: {
                    lines: { show: true },
                    points: { show: true }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, I think you need to wrap your array in another array...

```
$.plot($('.chart'), [store]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your x-axis mode to 'time', and provide the dates as timestamps in milliseconds.  See the [API Docs](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt) under the 'Time series data' heading for more information.